# Binding calculations to element properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a (moveable) dialog window whose initial position I want to offset from the right hand side of the app (its parent container is `Canvas`) based on whether some static windows are open or not.

As such I need something along the lines of this

```
<MyWindow Canvas.Right="{Binding Element.Width + Element2.Width}" />
```

This wouldnt entirely work though as if `Element1` wasnt visible I wouldnt want it in the calculation.  Perhaps the logical conclusion is that this cannot be done via binding alone and I'd need a property on the `ViewModel`.

This raises another issue in that each one of these elements (including the parent window) has its own `ViewModel`.  Would it not be against best practices for one of these `ViewModel`s to interact directly with Views to calculate this information?

Comment: Check this out [Impossible WPF Part 2: Binding Expressions](http://www.11011.net/wpf-binding-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MultiBinding](http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings) and calculate the total width in an `IMultiValueConverter`.

The `ActualWidth` property of an element should be 0 if it is collapsed, so you can use the element's `ActualWidth` property for the binding.